# What is the simplest way to get a negative DC power?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter

I have several voltages available and I need a -12v dc power for a DDS function generator.

The available powers I have are:
220v AC
15v DC
12vx2 DC
5v DC

Edit:
I tried the method where I connect the two 12v supplies together, and I can get the -12v this way when I test, but once I plug the cable to the generator the adapter disconnects and I lose the -12v, acting like the adapter was shorted.

https://forum.digikey.com/t/get-a-positive-and-negative-voltage-output-from-power-supply/10593

Comment: necessary current, and: what output voltages must your DDS provide? DDSes are typically used to generate AC voltages, and well, you could work off a single supply and just AC couple the DDS output, shifitng it to the desired voltage range. Anyways, I'm sure such exist, but I've never seen a DDS that needs -12V: that seems excessive.

Comment: your edit really answers none of the question we've asked!

Comment: It is really frustrating, I think I made a mistake buying this generator and UI have to live with it.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32794949155.html

Comment: that is useless without a datasheet, could you please link to the datasheet?

Comment: That's what I can find:
https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/F7L/TANB/IXLA7NZX/F7LTANBIXLA7NZX.pdf

Comment: Well, you can always just ignore that you've bought it and start doing something that actually fulfills your requirement (You might be able to reuse important parts!). Sadly, you've still not mentioned any of these requirements: which voltage ranges do you want to output? Which currents?

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do this is with a 78XX series DC DC converter, they can be wired to sink or source and provide positive or negative voltages. This is how to use a negative voltage from a positive one. Make sure you don't exceed the input to pin 3 voltage (32V for the P7812, which means you could use either 15V rails (27V span) or 12V rails (24V span))
They can also be paralleled (use small resistance or inductance between)

Here is a excerpt from the P7812 datasheet:

[image]
Source: https://www.cui.com/product/resource/p7805-s.pdf